# Why does type have no overlap when in enum?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I'm trying to wrap my head around why TypeScript reports that my condition will always be false due to no type overlap between `Action.UP | Action.DOWN` and `Action.LEFT` in this situation ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Component%3CS%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20state%3A%20S%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20render()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UP%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20DOWN%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20LEFT%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20RIGHT%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20action%3A%20Action%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20initialAction%3A%20Action.UP%20%7C%20Action.DOWN%20%3D%20Action.UP%3B%0D%0Aclass%20MyComponent%20extends%20Component%3CState%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20state%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action%3A%20initialAction%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20render()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Why%20is%20action%20not%20of%20type%20Action%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20isLateral%20%3D%20this.state.action%20%3D%3D%3D%20Action.LEFT%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)):

```
class Component<S> {
    public state: S;
    public render() {}
}

enum Action {
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
}

interface State {
    action: Action;
}

const initialAction: Action.UP | Action.DOWN = Action.UP;
class MyComponent extends Component<State> {
    public state = {
        action: initialAction,
    }

    public render() {
        // Why is action not of type Action as declared in the interface?
        const isLateral = this.state.action === Action.LEFT;
    }
}
```

If `this.state.action` only has an initial value of type `Action.UP | Action.DOWN`, but is declared as type `Action` in the interface, why can't I compare it to `Action.LEFT`? If I can reassign `this.state.action` in the future to be either `LEFT` or `RIGHT`, why is the condition always false?

Comment: Why  not set `state` in the constructor instead of re-defining it in the child class?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin This was meant to be an MVCE that mocks the way React looks since that's what I'm using.

Comment: Right... even so, why re-define the `state` property when it is already defined in React's `Component` class?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Forgive me (I'm new to TypeScript), but does TS distinguish between a class property and its initial value? I was under the impression I could avoid constructor boilerplate by assigning the class property (like with ECMAScript's proposed class properties).

Comment: Yes. TypeScript does distinguish between a class property and its initial value. You can assign the class property at the same time you define the class property. If you do that in a child class, though, you are re-defining the property in addition to setting its initial value.

Comment: What you were doing initially is the equivalent of this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20HasParent%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20prop%3A%20Parent%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20HasChild%20extends%20HasParent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20prop%20is%20now%20re-defined%20as%20type%20Child%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20prop%20%3D%20new%20Child()%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: Also, I added a quote to my answer which shows that using the constructor to set initial state is what the React docs recommend.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Okay, so is there any reason not to do `public state: MyState = { … }` as I'm used to ES syntax aside from the fact I need to explicit type it? This way I won't need the constructor.

Comment: Setting the initial state by re-defining the `Component` parent class's `state` property might be problematic in surprising ways. I'm afraid I don't know enough about React to know what surprises might await when we do not follow the docs.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Okay, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer to "Why?"

> Why is action not of type Action as declared in the interface?

It is of a different type because the child class is re-defining the `state` property and giving it a narrower type than it has in the parent class. If you are doing that by design, then you can access the broader interface of the parent class by casting inside `render()`.

```
const isLateral = (this as Component<State>).state.action === Action.LEFT;
```

### Recommended Approach

Alternatively, do what the [React Component documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) says:

> ...if your component needs to use local state, assign the initial state to this.state directly in the constructor:

That is, do not re-redefine the parent class's state property; instead, use the already defined `state` property that `extend` gives you. Set its initial value in the constructor.

```
class MyComponent extends Component<State> {

    constructor() { 
        super();
        this.state = {
            action: initialAction,
        }
    }

    public render() {
        const isLateral = this.state.action === Action.LEFT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to type the public state to State like this:

```
public state: State = {
    action: initialAction,
}
```

Otherwise Typescript will infer that `state.action` is the same type as `initialAction`.

### To answer the question in your comment

([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Component%3CS%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20state%3A%20S%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20count%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20render()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UP%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20DOWN%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20LEFT%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20RIGHT%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20action%3A%20Action%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20initialAction%3A%20Action.UP%20%7C%20Action.DOWN%20%3D%20Action.UP%3B%0D%0Aclass%20MyComponent%20extends%20Component%3CState%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20count%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action%3A%20initialAction%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20render()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Why%20is%20action%20not%20of%20type%20Action%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20isLateral%20%3D%20this.state.action%20%3D%3D%3D%20Action.LEFT%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20is%20ok%20even%20though%20Component%3CState%3E.type%20is%20a%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.count%20%3D%20'Not%20a%20number'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

You redefined the value and type of `state` in your child class when you set as a new property.

My link illustrates that. I've added a new property on the parent class called `count` with a type `number`. If I define it in my child class as a new property, it infers it as `any`, and thus can be set to a string within `render()`.

However, you can see how I handled your original `state` property. In order to use the parent's state type, you can call `super()` in the constructor and then define `this.state.action = initialAction;`.

That way, when you call `render()` it will be looking for the `Action` type on `this.state.action`, and not the newly defined `Action.UP | Action.DOWN`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But why do I have to respecify if the class `Component` defines `public state: S`?

Answer (score 0):

in our case we forgot `{}` as `const A: React.FC<IProps> = (first, second, ...rest)` had to be `const A: React.FC<IProps> = ({first, second, ...rest})`. This is awful :)